# Video attached to a card no longer working

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

my glassware is no longer working properly with attached videos to a card.
Something changed in the glass firmware that can cause this?
SYMPTOM: After tapping "Play" in the menu item for the card the video seems to start loading but never starts.

BACKGROUND: the code was working till some days ago ( maybe a couple of weeks ) and was coded something like:

```
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(io.BytesIO(content), attachment['contentType'],
                        resumable=True)  
self.mirror_service.timeline().insert(body=body, media_body=media).execute()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in XE12. It's being tracked in the official issue tracker in [issue number 387](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=387).

Comment: I updated my answer to include a link to the issue in the tracker. If you star that issue, you'll be notified when it is updated.

Comment: Thanks, is there any workaround? such as setting menuitem with payload. I desperately need this feature.